# Python facebook api about the limit and summary

Tags: python

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/custom-integrations/examples
there are example: download.py,in the function: `def getFeed(group, name):`

There is a piece of it:

```
params = "?fields=permalink_url,from,story,type,message,link,created_time,updated_time,likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),comments.limit(0).summary(total_count)"
```

What does the `likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),comments.limit(0).summary(total_count)` mean?
Specifically, what does `limit(0)` mean, and what does  `summary(total_count)` mean?

Also, in this download.py, there is

```
DEFAULT_LIMIT = "100"# Set to true if you like seeing console output
```

What does this `DEFAULT_LIMIT` mean? Does it mean 100 pages or 100 feeds (posts)?

Answer (score 0):

The params looks like just a strangely written get request. You can see in the code that it is sent to the server just like any other get request and returns text just like a get request too.

In a get request you have your url ex. youtube.com/watch and a questionmark denotes a get request just like the one at the beginning of the params string. What it is doing is sending a variable called fields to the server.

Additionally it is appending the variable limit (denoted by an ampersand or &) and setting it to 100, along with finally sending the "since" variable.

So, yes. Default limit is specifying how many entries you want to get in response to your get request.